# ngModel validação não funciona em campo select

Tags: angular, typescript

Estou tentando colocar uma validação required no select pra depois mostrar caso  o usuário deixe de preencher.

Tentei algo como:

```
 <select required #selecttipoproduto="ngModel" (change)="setTipoProduto(tipoDoProduto)" [(ngModel)]="tipoDoProduto" name="selecttipoproduto" id="selecttipoproduto" class="browser-default custom-select">
    <option class="dropdown-item" disabled>{{tipoDoProduto || 'Tipo do Produto'}}</option>
    <option [hidden]="tipoprodutos[k].tipo == tipoDoProduto" *ngFor="let tipoProduto of tipoprodutos; let k = index">{{tipoProduto.tipo}}</option>
 </select>

<div class="input-invalido animated shake" *ngIf="submited && selecttipoproduto.errors">
  Tipo do produto é obrigatório
</div>
```

Estou usando essa mesma forma em um campo input, porém nele aparece a mensagem. Exemplo:

```
<input #nome="ngModel" [(ngModel)]="produto.nome" maxlength="60" name="nome" id="nome" required
                    type="text" class="form-control">

<div class="input-invalido animated shake" *ngIf="submited && nome.errors">
   Nome do produto é obrigatório
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O required só funciona no select se o value da primeira opção for ""

```
<select required #selecttipoproduto="ngModel" (change)="setTipoProduto(tipoDoProduto)" [(ngModel)]="tipoDoProduto" name="selecttipoproduto" id="selecttipoproduto" class="browser-default custom-select">
        <option class="dropdown-item" value="" disabled>{{tipoDoProduto || 'Tipo do Produto'}}</option>
        <option [hidden]="tipoprodutos[k].tipo == tipoDoProduto" *ngFor="let tipoProduto of tipoprodutos; let k = index">{{tipoProduto.tipo}}</option>
 </select>
```